# Angular - Do not load component from API if data already exist

Tags: angular

I have a component  app-list which is called in all the components.I have two other components app-cmp1 and app-cmp2.

In each of the component app-cmp1 and app-cmp2 we have called app-list and app-list loads data from an api.app-list is hidden by default. When user clicks on a link, the  opens up.

The issue  now each time the App-list is opened, it loads data from the api. Is there a way we can prevent app-list from calling the api if the data is loaded once.

Comment: Have u tried Ngrx (http://ngrx.io/)? I think it addresses cases like yours - seperating views from data. You can implement the `data.loaded` check in the store and have a very clean component

Answer (score 0):

you can cache the data inside the called service and check if it's available at call time :

**inside the called service :**

```
...
data : any ;

fetchData(forceReload : boolean) : Observable<any>{
   if (!forceReload && this.data){
       return of(data) ;
   }
return this.http.get(url)
       .pipe(
        tap(resp => this.data = resp)
        ) ;
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build an observable-based cache layer:

```
export class CachedDataService {

    private cache: { [index: string]: { reloader: Subject<void>, data: Observable<any> } } = {};

    constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

    public get<T>(url: string, reloadIfExists = false): Observable<T> {
        if (this.cache[url] === undefined) {
            const reloader = new BehaviorSubject<void>(null);
            this.cache[url] = {
                reloader: reloader,
                data: reloader.pipe(
                    switchMapTo(this.http.get<T>(url))
                )
            };
        } else if (reloadIfExists) {
            this.cache[url].reloader.next();
        }
        return this.cache[url].data;
    }

}
```

this way, you can fetch data as you want, and you have full control on the reloader, which will propagate the reloaded data to all the subscribers.